# Arduino button trigger coding

Tags: arduino-nano, code-review, attiny85

I am trying to write a simple coding to change the color of an RGB LED using a push button trigger.  I just need the the pin output to change when the button is pressed.  I would like to do this using just an ATTiny85 and uploading the code to it using an Arduino Nano.  I don't have much coding experience so I was hoping someone would take a quick look at my attempt and tell me if it will work.

```
// here are the pin number assignments

int blue = 2;

int green = 1;

int red = 0;

int button = 4; // the pin the button is on.

int choice = 0; // mode selection


void setup() {

  // initialize the pwm pins as outputs.

  pinMode(red, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(green, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(blue, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(button, INPUT);

  analogWrite(red, 255);

  analogWrite(green, 255);

  analogWrite(blue, 255);


}

void loop() {

  // read the pushbutton to see if it's been pushed
  int val;
  val = digitalRead(button);

  // val = HIGH means the button has been pushed
  // and the mode is to be changed.

// SELECT CHOICE //////////////////////////////////////////////////

  if (val == HIGH) {
    choice = choice + 1;

    analogWrite(blue, 255);
    analogWrite(green, 255);
    analogWrite(red, 255);
    delay(500);

    // indicate mode transition with blue flashes
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      analogWrite(blue, 125);
      delay(20);
      analogWrite(blue, 255);
      delay(40);
    }

    delay(500);

    // change this if you want more modes

    if (choice == 5) {
      choice = 0;
    }
  }


  while (val == HIGH) {
    delay(100);
    val = digitalRead(button);
  }

  //////////////////////////////


  // OFF

  if (choice == 0) {
    analogWrite(red, 0);
    analogWrite(green, 0);
    analogWrite(blue, 0);

  }

  // RED

  if (choice == 1) {
    analogWrite(red, 255);
    analogWrite(green, 0);
    analogWrite(blue, 0);

  }

  // GREEN
  if (choice == 2) {
    analogWrite(red, 0);
    analogWrite(green, 255);
    analogWrite(blue, 0);
  }

  // BLUE

  if (choice == 3) {
    analogWrite(red, 0);
    analogWrite(green, 0);
    analogWrite(blue, 255);
  }

  // AMBER
  if (choice == 4) {
    analogWrite(red, 255);
    analogWrite(green, 255);
    analogWrite(blue, 0);
  }

}
```

Any input?

Comment: You could look at the one shot button press example in the Arduino IDE and that change may be able to remove some of the delays in your code that prevent debounce.

Comment: The problem with the one shot button example (and apparently with my own code) is the action doesn't stick.  The LEDs only light up when the button is pressed.  When I let go of the button, the LEDs go out.  I need them to stay on when the button is release and change to the next color when the button is pressed again.  Any idea how to make that happen?